# Finding life expectancy from a century ( Eloquent Javascript exercise 5.3)

Tags: javascript

**Question**

Given some JSON Data display the average life expectancy in a century.
Here is some sample JSON data since theres quite a bit

```
 '{"name": "Carolus Haverbeke", "sex": "m", "born": 1832, "died": 1905, "father": "Carel Haverbeke", "mother": "Maria van Brussel"}',
  '{"name": "Emma de Milliano", "sex": "f", "born": 1876, "died": 1956, "father": "Petrus de Milliano", "mother": "Sophia van Damme"}',
  '{"name": "Maria de Rycke", "sex": "f", "born": 1683, "died": 1724, "father": "Frederik de Rycke", "mother": "Laurentia van Vlaenderen"}',
  '{"name": "Jan van Brussel", "sex": "m", "born": 1714, "died": 1748, "father": "Jacobus van Brussel", "mother": "Joanna van Rooten"}',
```

Now the output will look something like

```
// → 16: 43.5
//   17: 51.2
//   18: 52.8
//   19: 54.8
//   20: 84.7
//   21: 94
```

Of course the numbers on the side refer to what century you are on

**The answer**

```
function average(array) {
  function plus(a, b) { return a + b; }
  return array.reduce(plus) / array.length;
}

function groupBy(array, groupOf) {
  var groups = {};
  array.forEach(function(element) {
    var groupName = groupOf(element);
    if (groupName in groups)
      groups[groupName].push(element);
    else
      groups[groupName] = [element];
  });
  return groups;
}

var byCentury = groupBy(ancestry, function(person) {
  return Math.ceil(person.died / 100);
});

for (var century in byCentury) {
  var ages = byCentury[century].map(function(person) {
    return person.died - person.born;
  });
  console.log(century + ": " + average(ages));
}

// → 16: 43.5
//   17: 51.2
//   18: 52.8
//   19: 54.8
//   20: 84.7
//   21: 94
```

**My Issues**

After taking a look at the problem for a solid 15 minutes, I didnt have much a clue. The solution is a bit confusing to me as well. Particularly

`if (groupName in groups)`
 but how can this statement ever be true? groups is set to an empty array?

Now the rest

```
 groups[groupName].push(element);
    else
      groups[groupName] = [element];
```

Here `groups` is an empty object, and `groupName` is a function. This is a bit confusing. I thought inside [] we always have to have a number, for example in an array =`[1,2,3,4,5]` we say that `array[0]` is 1. What are these three lines saying? Thank you.

Comment: The solution is from the book, I didnt write it, just trying to understand it

Comment: "`groupName` is a function". Nope, it's a number returned by `groupOf`. `groups` was set to an empty _object_ outside of `forEach`, `else` in the callback will populate `groups` during the iteration.

Comment: Actually `groups` is set to an empty object, not an empty array. And it doesn't stay empty long, as `groups[groupName] = [element];` does fill it with arrays in cases where the `groupName` key doesn't already exist.

Comment: Ah yes groupName is a number. Then it goes to the if statement, and its not true so it goes to else. So how does groups[groupName] = [element] work. How can you do object[number]? I thoughts its always array[index]? Also why did we put element in square brackets? To just make it an array?

Comment: [Property accessors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors). And yes, `elements` are put to brackets to create an array with one member.

Comment: So what is the purpose of element here? What does it mean / represent

Comment: Please follow the comments in the code in Jared's answer, that should explain it all.

Comment: I think I get it now! I'm just a bit confused on why we need to put square brackets around elements?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could be forgiven for misunderstanding this, later versions of javascript have better ways to do this. What you're really doing is making buckets of related things:

```
function groupBy(array, groupOf) {
  var groups = {}; // empty (for now)
  array.forEach(function(element) {
    var groupName = groupOf(element); // uses the function groupOf to get a string
    if (groupName in groups) // if that string is already a key in the hash
      groups[groupName].push(element); // push into the array in the hash
    else
      groups[groupName] = [element]; // create an array in that hash with element at its first index
  });
  return groups;
}
```

The code here is conditionally creating an array in the object keyed by group name, e.g. `groups['foo'][0]` would be the first element in the foo group. As you iterate through the elements, sort them into that initially empty object in buckets (arrays) by groupName (property key).

The way this is typically done now would be to use `reduce`:

```
array.reduce(function(groups, element) {
  var groupName = groupOf(element);
  if (groupName in groups)
    groups[groupName].push(element);
  else
    groups[groupName] = [element];

  return groups;
}, {});
```

## UPDATE

### The many uses of the square bracket `[]` operator:

The `[]` operator can be used for setting/getting a property by string key on a JavaScript object, setting/getting an array element at an integer index, constructing an array literal, or destructuring bind.

```
var foo = {};            // an object literal
foo['bar'] = 'pizza';    // setting the 'bar' property.
console.log(foo['bar']); // accessing 'bar' property, prints 'pizza' to the console.
```

While the above is usually written `foo.bar` instead of `foo['bar']` and in this case would be equivalent, the square bracket notation can do things that the dot notation can't, like keys with spaces or a variable:

```
foo['the pizza'] = 'pepperoni';
var str = 'whatever';
foo[str] = 'psssh yeah right';
console.log(foo['whatever'] === foo.whatever === foo[str]); // true
```

Or keys that start with numbers like '7z' or whatnot. You can also do `foo[17] = 'whatever'` or `foo[{}] = 'other thing'` but **this is a bad idea**. The keys will silently be cast to strings ('17' and '[object Object]') and this is a common source of errors. Your object property keys should always be strings or symbols (which I mention for completeness, don't worry if you don't know what symbols are). The first has the added confusion of making foo look like an array, as they are accessed with the same square bracket but use integer indicies:

```
var arr = [];        // an array literal
arr.push('sausage'); // adds an element
console.log(arr[0]); // accesses the first element, prints 'sausage'
arr[0] = 'veggie';   // changes the element at index 0
console.log(arr[0]); // prints 'veggie'
```

We constructed an empty array literal above, but they don't have to be empty:

```
var ints = [0, 1, 2, 3]; // a four element array
var single = [element];  // creates a one-element array with the value of the variable element
```

#### Advanced use

The 2015 update to JavaScript brought us destructuring bind, which I mention for completeness but is a comparatively advanced use case:

```
let arr = [1, 'qux'];
let [something, otherthing] = arr;
console.log(something);  // 1
console.log(otherthing); // 'qux'
```

The second line above desugars to the following:

```
let something = arr[0];
let otherthing = arr[1];
```

And it can also be used in function definitions:

```
let sum = function([a, b]) { return a + b; }; // note the brackets
let arr = [2, 8];
console.log(sum(arr)); // 10
```

The above desugars to:

```
let sum = function(array) {
  let a = array[0];
  let b = array[1];
  return a + b;
};
```

Comment: What is element doing exactly? I'm just trying to piece together of how I should approach this, because I'm kind of lost and not sure how to start. I appreciate your answer though

Comment: "*later versions of javascript have better ways to do this*" - which (just curious)?

Comment: For example suppose the person was born in the 16th century. So groupName would be 16 right? So what groups[16] = [element], what does that imply?

Comment: Is it basically taking all properties with the return value 16,17 etc etc and pushing the objects( which here is element) into groups?

Comment: @cresjoy correct, that is essentially what is happening. I think part of what is confusing you is that the `[]` operator is overloaded to both index into an array and access a hash/object by string key. `groups[16] = [element]` could actually (depending on context) mean one of two things: an object has a property keyed to the string '16' (implicitly converted) of a one element array or an array has another array at index 16 (integer) consisting of one element.

Comment: @Bergi since the example doesn't use any ecmascript features > 3 I assumed it was ES3, as you well know ES5 brought us reduce.

Comment: @JaredSmith: `reduce` isn't of much help here, since we're mutating `groups` anyway and can use a sideeffectful loop just as well. It reduces the function from 11 to 10 lines, not a big difference. I thought you were referring to a `Map` or so…

Comment: So we do we need to put element in a square bracket then?

Comment: @cresjoy too long for a comment, see the update in my answer.

Comment: Great answer. I'm still unsure if my reasoning is correct so hear me out. The reason we put [element] in our piece of code, is so that we can make the object an array. If the object is an array, we can use array methods like push.. etc etc. This is why,right?

Comment: @cresjoy no that's not right. `group` is still an object. You are creating a *new* array and putting `element` in it. `groupName` is a variable whose value is a string. That string value is being used as a key to assign that new array to the `group` object. For a clearer example, its like you wrote `var arr = []; arr.push(element); group['somestring'] = arr;`. Or something like this `var group = { 'somestring': [element] };` All are equivalent.

Comment: Right, so we put [element] to indicate that groups[groupName] is indeed an array. Without [element] as opposed to element. It would assume that groups[groupName] is an object?

Comment: @cresjoy without the brackets `[]`, then `groups[groupName] = element` means that `groups[groupName]` happens to be the value of the variable 'element', with the brackets its an array with the value of the variable 'element' at index 0. Or to translate the line into English "The value of the 'groups' object at the string key (which is the value of the variable 'groupName') is an array whose first element is the value of the variable 'element'".

Comment: Makes sense. Appreciate your help.. this is truly confusing stuff